# How to remove notifications when touched?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am trying to develop an app that will make notifications when you exit. But I want that when you touch the notification and you reopen the application, the notification disappears. How i can do it?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_land);
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


        mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
                    .setContentTitle("Mensaje de Alerta")
                    .setContentText("Ejemplo de notificación.")
                    .setContentInfo("4")
                    .setTicker("Alerta!");

        }


    public void salir(View view) {

        finish();
        Intent notIntent =
                new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            PendingIntent contIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    MainActivity.this, 0, notIntent, 0);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                mNotificationManager.notify("NOTIFICATION", 0, mBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

This code only makes the Notification and it opens the app again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using flags

```
 notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Using Notification builder

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Using Notification Manager

```
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

for API level 18 and above

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public class MyNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {...}
...

private void clearNotificationExample(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    myNotificationListenerService.cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(), sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
}
```

Comment: but in my code.. where i put this code?

Comment: try with setting flag in NotificationCompat.Builder